# The best way to write large SQL query result in CSV file using Java and Spring

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL DB, and I need to write several query results in CSV (each select result need to be written in its own CSV file):

```
1. SELECT column1, column2 + column7 as value1, ..., column5 FROM table1;
2. SELECT column1, column2, ..., column5 FROM table2;
...
```

The problem is - these queries retrieve ~ 10 - 12 millions of rows. So maybe it will be necessary to divide each SQL results on parts and write it to several files (because of timeout). I need to make an app that can do the work on local machine, and the database runs on remote server.
What is the best way to do it? On Java (and Spring) preferably. Is it possible, after all?

Comment: Use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) via the Postgres JDBC driver [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/server-prepare/#copymanager)?

Comment: Like Adrian said, use COPY. By a large margin the best performing solution.

Comment: I will try, thank you. Is COPY requires special admin privileges?

Comment: Define what do you mean by best.

Comment: No, for `COPY TO STDOUT` (the one you need) you only need SELECT permissions on the tables, views, etc.